# Select2 deafult value from hidden input

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-select2

Is it possible to Select2 starts with value from hidden field?

`<input type="hidden" name="airport" value="GIG" />`

Like: `$("input[name='airport']").select2().val('GIG')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idOfTheSelect").val($("input[name='airport']").val());
```

I suppouse that the value of the hidden input is one of the options of the select

Comment: Does not work. Thats not a normal select. Its a select2 jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
$("input[name='airport']").select2('val','the option of value')
```